# connecting to a sharepoint online document library, with interactive powershell session.

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am aware of how to connect to a sharepoint online via SPOService, but this does not allow me to run powershell scripts on the file system itself does it?  say a document library.

If you open a sharepoint online document library with explorer, document library/library tab/open in explorer, then you can right click and run a ps1 file that will open up a local powershell session with the pwd of the sharepoint file system like this:

PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\contoso.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\site\shared documents

from this command prompt its just like any other, i now have an interactive session..except i want to open this same type of session as our global tenant, so i can run some scripts that will convert all old office formats to the new xml format, because we will have a lot of E2 users using these sharepoint doc libraries, who will not be able to open or edit old formats.

now i can log into a pc as the domain user that is the global tenant, but i'd rather not if i can somehow get the same result by mounting the doc library file system through some sort of enter-pssession type of connection.

This is all so i can run a bulk xml format converter on sharepoint doc libraries that we are in the process of uploading to various company sites. i can run the script fine here on site, on our file server, but when i run it from the sharepoint online site, i get a lot of confirm prompts, unblock-file prompts, ect... so i feel it has to be a permissions issue because the PS session is running under the local domain user who's logged in. i probably murdered this question, but im not sure how else to put it.